# Reactjs cannot navigate directly to url(Springboot backend)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

My project setup.

Backend: Springboot, exposing various REST API's
Frontend: React Js. 
Build: I am using maven `frontend-maven-plugin` and `maven-antrun-plugin` to build my react project using npm and package it with the springboot jar.

My react js Router class looks like this

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Redirect
        exact
        from="/"
        to="/dashboard"
      />
      <RouteWithLayout
        component={DashboardView}
        exact
        layout={MainLayout}
        path="/dashboard"
      />
       .......
       .......
```

I run my jar using `java -jar ....` command. When I try to reach `http://<host:port>` it redirects me to `http://<host:port>/dashboard`, which is fine. All the navigations from here on works fine according to my routes and each view, calls backend endpoints to serve the content in the page.

Problem is when I try to nagivate to any of the page directly, for example If I type `http://<host:port>/dashboard` in my browser, I get 404 Not found(thrown by springboot).

I believe the problem is that, springboot is trying to search for the endpoint `/dashboard` which is not there in the backend and hence 404 is thrown. How can I indicate reactjs or springboot that this url needs to be rendered the same way as when it was done through `/`

I am not sure if this problem needs to be fixed on backend(Springboot) or frontend(React js routes).

Does any one has any idea?

Comment: In the controller class add a request mapping to `/dashboard` and handle the request accordingly?

Comment: I cannot do this for every single url path. This cannot be a solution right